# Image manipulation in HTML5 canvas is not working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am doing a course on HTML5 canvas. I used some of the codes taught. those work in the tutorial, but when i tried, the image is not changing at all. 
here is my code for inverting colors:-

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <canvas width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
  <script>
   var c =  document.querySelector("canvas");
   var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

function doIt() {
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0, 1000, 1000);
  var length = imageData.data.length / 4;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
      imageData.data[i * 4 + 0] = 255 - imageData.data[i * 4 + 0];   //Red
      imageData.data[i * 4 + 1] = 255 - imageData.data[i * 4 + 1];   //Green
      imageData.data[i * 4 + 2] = 255 - imageData.data[i * 4 + 2];   //Blue
  }
  // Comment this line to see original image
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  doIt();
}
image.src = 'rgb.png';
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Pls help me where i am going wrong

Comment: Your code works for me when run locally. When you run the code, is your image file `rgb.png` getting loaded locally - as appears to the case in your example - or is it coming from a remote server?

Comment: @almcd the image is saved in the same folder as html. it is not in server.

Comment: If you load the html as file (file://) then it is considered cross-origin. Load from a simple server so your page is hosted via `http://localhost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly confident that the issue you're having is related to the fact that the image that is being loaded is [tainting the canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image).

The example below, is the same as your code, except for the fact that it:

1. Serves the image from a server with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set to allow requests from any origin
2. Sets `image.crossOrigin` to `anonymous`

For contrast, you can see the unaltered image at: http://so-answers.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/rgb.png.

```js
var c =  document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

function doIt() {
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0, 1000, 1000);
  var length = imageData.data.length / 4;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
      imageData.data[i * 4 + 0] = 255 - imageData.data[i * 4 + 0];   //Red
      imageData.data[i * 4 + 1] = 255 - imageData.data[i * 4 + 1];   //Green
      imageData.data[i * 4 + 2] = 255 - imageData.data[i * 4 + 2];   //Blue
  }
  // Comment this line to see original image
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  doIt();
}
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
image.src = 'http://so-answers.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/rgb.png';
```

```html
<canvas width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

**Edit:**

If you serve your HTML, JavaScript files and image all from the same server (could be the same directory too, but that's not a prerequisite), in development, or in production, then you won't have any cross origin issues.

For local development you could do this with Python, using the built-in web server, by running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` from the command line, in the directory that contains your files. See http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/how-to-use-simplehttpserver/ for more details.

If you serve the image from a different domain than your HTML and JavaScript files (in development, or in production) then you will encounter a cross origin issue. This can be addressed by the changes I've made in the example above.

Additionally, as K3N says in their comment to your question, you will also get a cross origin issue if you just load the files directly into your browser without running a local development server.

Comment: can i use a python server to host the image? by adding the server to same directory?

Comment: @Gameatro I've edited my answer above to respond to your question. Hope that helps.

Comment: well another question. after i create server, should i open the html file or the server address? would it be any different?

Comment: @Gameatro If you've created your local development server by running, `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`, you'll then want to access your site in your browser via http://localhost:8000.